# WiFi32 module examples not compiled

Tags: pic, mplab

Just downloaded the project from Harmony 3 with all the relevant libraries and when hitting compile i'm getting lot of errors.

When compiling a project contain free rtos+usb cdc+rtc+nvm its works fine, but after adding the wifi it fail.

Include video of the entire process, from adding the project to compiling it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HADJdTM_noE

Something is wrong with the ide, installed on another laptop and got the same problems. support ticket open two weeks ago and they cant help.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: its not about the message, when you fix one there are more and more... its a libraries issue

Answer (score 0):

All had to do is to donwload ALL the harmony content there are. (33Gb)